# Grep and Cut command in linux

Tags: bash, grep, csv, cut, gnu

I have a csv file with loads of data. I wish to cut the 9th column for values >=1 and then use grep to display full rows that match.

Sample format:

```
ABC,XYZ,RTY,CREAM,FRANCE,170019,ST REMY CREME,3035540005229,0.75,1,15,26.99,10       
ABC,RDS,XSD,SPICE,NETHERLANDS,390476,THE KINGS GINGER,5010493025621,1.5,1,41,49.95,NA      
ABC,RMS,DKS,TABLE WINE RED,CHILE,400176,SANTA ISABELA,63657001349,3,1,12.5,31.99,0
```

I have tried with

```
grep . Myfile.csv |cut -d"," -f9 | sort  |grep -E  "^(1*[1-9][2-9]*(\.[2-9]+)?|1+\.[2-9]*[1-9][2-9]*)$"
```

but it only shows the 9th column values not the full rows with all the columns.

and also

```
grep $(cut -d"," -f9 Myfile.csv | grep -E  "^(1*[1-9][2-9]*(\.[2-9]+)?|1+\.[2-9]*[1-9][2-9]*)$") Myfile.csv
```

Any help would be great.

PS: can't use awk (:-

Comment: Possibly same assignment posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344840/pattern-matching-using-grep)

Comment: Why can't you use awk? It is a standard tool and should be available on just about _any_ *nix environment. Do you just mean you don't know how to use it?

Comment: @terdon reading between the lines, its homework and limiting the tools available helps reduce the solution set size.  One could probably do this with perl or excel or powerhell, but it wouldn't test the learning.    Any answer involving awk etc would be "Not an answer"

Comment: @Criggie yes, I guessed as much but I am afraid we won't cater to that kind of artificial limitation. We are happy to help users get around actual limitations of their systems but not absolutely pointless ones imposed by a teacher. Awk and the like are the right tools for the job, so that's what our answers should use because that way they will be useful to all the future users who'll see this question, none of whom will have any problem using something as portable as awk.

Comment: @steeldriver should there be a [homework] tag?  serious question.

Comment: @Criggie maybe... tbh I don't really involve myself in the [meta](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/) aspects of the site - perhaps that's a question you should post there?

Comment: I voted to close this because the question belongs on StackOverflow. A Unix system **by definition** has Awk. It's described in POSIX. How do I solve this without using specific Unix tools is not useful for future visitors to this site.

Comment: [Meta has discussed and blacklisted the homework tag](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/992/tip-for-trogdor-please-eat-our-homework); we can revisit if there's a need.

Answer (score 13):

Although you state `awk` is not a possibility - for the sake of completeness:

```
awk -F',' '$9>=1' input.csv
```

This will instruct `awk` to consider `,` as field separator and print only lines where field 9 has a value equal or larger than 1.

Answer (score 8):

Using `csvsql`:

Assuming your file csv file as:

```
$ cat input.csv
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13
ABC,XYZ,RTY,CREAM,FRANCE,170019,ST REMY CREME,3035540005229,0.75,1,15,26.99,10   
ABC,RDS,XSD,SPICE,NETHERLANDS,390476,THE KINGS GINGER,5010493025621,1.5,1,41,49.95,NA
ABC,RMS,DKS,TABLE WINE RED,CHILE,400176,SANTA ISABELA,63657001349,3,1,12.5,31.99,0
```

This would do:

```
<input.csv csvsql  --query "select * from stdin where col9 >=1 "
```

You can change `col9` with column name in header in csvfile.

---

Using `miller`:

Please install [miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) for running the command.

```
mlr --csv filter '$col9 >= 1' input.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

try

```
grep -E "^([^,]+,){8}[1-9][0-9]*(.[1-9]+)?" MyFile.csv
```

where

- `-E` tell `grep` to use extended regular expression
- `^` begin of line
- `[^,]+,` match not a comma, one or more time, a comma
- `( ){8}` repeat 8 time (including trailing comma)
- `[1-9][0-9]*(.[1-9]+)?` leading non 0 optional dot part

thanks to Daniel Junglas for repeating pattern.

Comment: That's a seriously limited set of real number formats (OK for current case, not for production code). Beware `Nan`, `Inf`, `1.3e-04`, `0.3e+05`, `-2`, `1String` are all on the edge in various ways.

Answer (score 2):

`cut` is not necessary, `sort` can do the field inspection for you, then add a component to the regex to go past the first 8 fields:

```
sort -t"," -k9 MyFile.csv | grep -E "^([^,]*,){8}(1*[1-9][2-9]*(\.[2-9]+)?|1+\.[2-9]*[1-9][2-9]*)"
```

`[^,]*,` means any number of non-comma characters followed by a comma, then `{8}` means 8 repeats. Note this needs the `-E` flag to `grep`

Comment: I'm curious, why would you need `sort` at all?

Comment: @AdminBee the OP used `sort` in his first example

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne '.put if .split(",")[8] >= 1;'
```

Sample Input:

```
ABC,XYZ,RTY,CREAM,FRANCE,170019,ST REMY CREME,3035540005229,0.75,1,15,26.99,10       
ABC,RDS,XSD,SPICE,NETHERLANDS,390476,THE KINGS GINGER,5010493025621,1.5,1,41,49.95,NA      
ABC,RMS,DKS,TABLE WINE RED,CHILE,400176,SANTA ISABELA,63657001349,3,1,12.5,31.99,0
```

Sample Output:

```
ABC,RDS,XSD,SPICE,NETHERLANDS,390476,THE KINGS GINGER,5010493025621,1.5,1,41,49.95,NA      
ABC,RMS,DKS,TABLE WINE RED,CHILE,400176,SANTA ISABELA,63657001349,3,1,12.5,31.99,0
```

Briefly, the `-ne` commandline flags tell Raku to expect code, and to run it linewise without autoprinting. Linewise data loads into the `$_` topic variable. The `.split()` call is short for `$_.split`, meaning that split will work on that data.

The `[8]` zero-indexed 8th column is then selected, and tested to see if its numeric value is `>= 1`. If so, then `$_` is `put`, which could be written `$_.put` but is here abbreviated as `.put`. (So the whole `$_` input line gets out`put` if the conditional is satisfied).

Finally, sometimes its useful to "blank out" non-grepped lines, leaving matching lines at the same position. The below Raku code performs that task, returning a blank first line:

```perl
~$ raku -ne '.grep(*.split(",")[8] >= 1).put;'  file

ABC,RDS,XSD,SPICE,NETHERLANDS,390476,THE KINGS GINGER,5010493025621,1.5,1,41,49.95,NA      
ABC,RMS,DKS,TABLE WINE RED,CHILE,400176,SANTA ISABELA,63657001349,3,1,12.5,31.99,0
```

https://raku.org